# LPT Printer Indents Text When Printed

Tags: linux, bash, printer

I originally posted this at Stack Overflow but I thought it would be more appropriate here:

My LPT? printer (HP Deskjet 420) is indenting text when I print to it:

```
echo -e "this is text" > /dev/lp0
echo -e "moretext" > /dev/lp0
echo -e "also text" > /dev/lp0
```

Output:

```
this is text
            moretext
                    alsotext
```

How do I have each line be directly below the line before?

Using Lubuntu with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem, enable the newline (-n) flag when echoing text, and follow every command with

```
\n\r
```

What this does is the command makes a newline manually then prints a carriage return, which literally returns the print carriage to the beginning of the new line. Example bash code:

```
echo -e -n "this is text\n\r" > /dev/lp0
echo -e -n "moretext\n\r" > /dev/lp0
echo -e -n "also text\n\r" > /dev/lp0
```

Should print:

```
this is text
moretext
alsotext
```